# Android :: How to disconnect from a wifi network?

Tags: android, wifi

I have Googled and find many sites saying about 'disabling Wifi radio'. But in my case, I just want the android device to disconnect from a specific wifi network(SSID preknown) without switching OFF the WiFi radio. Please give me some insights on this issue

Answer (score 19):

Wow this shouldn't have taken a month to be answered.

Here's the easiest way that I usually use:

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifi.disconnect();
 discon = new DisconnectWifi();
 registerReceiver(discon, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Where DisconnectWifi is just a small class the extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
  public class DisconnectWifi extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if(!intent.getParcelableExtra(wifi.EXTRA_NEW_STATE).toString().equals(SupplicantState.SCANNING)) wifi.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just need the first two lines.

Comment: This can't be done without installing an app or becoming an android developer? Wtf v~v

Comment: waking up ancient question's comments :D - my feeling is even if you can disconnect programatically, the system will immediately attempt to reconnect to saved networks! Since you need to save a network to connect to it, you can only REALLY disconnect if you forget it beforehand, which is a big NO-NO, as the user might not even configured the network himself, then he never gets to connect without "the IT guy".

Comment: wifi.disconnect(); is deprecated in android 10 and above.